# python3.7 subprocess.Popen throws "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" on one R-Pi but not the other, both running buster

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, subprocess

Unfortunately I can't use `shell=True` or `cwd=whatever/..`, I don't want a subshell.

Neither providing the full path of the command or setting the PATH environment variable makes any difference.  Calling `shutil.which()` on the command returns the expected path.  I've tried providing the command as a string and as a list.

But, as mentioned, what is really killing me is that the identical code works perfectly on a slightly newer R-Pi with an identical directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

*(Moved solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer section)*.

The second R-Pi had no `/usr/bin/bash`, only `/bin/bash` ..
Shell files being called by Popen had `#!/usr/bin/bash` headers, so 'file not found' was the correct error, but it was *interpreter not found*, rather than script not found, as I'd assumed!